# Data validation gives error normal cell doesnt

Tags: excel

I have this formula

```
=OFFSET(Products[[#Headers];[Merk]];
MATCH(A2;Producten!$A:$A;0)-1;1;COUNTIF(Producten!$A:$A;A2);1)
```

It works fine in a normal cell. But as soon as I putt it in the Data Validation>List I get the error.

[image]

There is a problem with this formula.
Not trying to type a formula?

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Well the List validation requires the result of the cell be either blank or a value from the specified list - so I would presume that the result of the formula isn't an acceptable value.

Comment: @AaronContreras, in this case, the purpose of the formula is to define the acceptable values of the data validation…

Comment: Updated the question with the error, please confirm it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to change the reference to the `Table` for the cell address (e.g. assuming the table starts at `B6` and `Merk` is the 1st field then change `Products[[#Headers];[Merk]]` for `B6`).

Not all formulas that are valid for `Cells` are accepted by `DataValidation`, particularly when they refer to a `ListObject` for example the formula `COUNTA(Products[Merk])`is valid in a `Cell` but not accepted by `DataValidation`

Formula should be:

```
=OFFSET(B6;
MATCH(A2;Producten!$A:$A;0)-1;1;COUNTIF(Producten!$A:$A;A2);1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a table in a validation formula you cannot refer directly to a table and must use intermediate names.
For example, define a name like this:
_name_Product that is equal to: ="Products[[#Headers];[Merk]"
Then use INDIRECT in the formula:
INDIRECT(_name_Product)
or use entries like INDIRECT("Products[[#Headers];[Merk]")

Hope this helps.